# how to use routing for NON-SPA in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm working in a project which has `WebApis`, which will communicate with database via business layers and return data, now on Presentation Layer, we want to use simple `html pages, Angular2 and typescript`.

I've gone through many videos/blogs and solutions for Angular applications but all of them are mostly for SPA (single-page-application).

**Here we don't want to go for SPA, on click of html page it should redirect to different page.**

**So our concern is how to use routing here for not SPA applications?**

**how to use layout, we are not supposed to have headers and menu (or master layout) in all the pages, so how can we create layout page and set them as a master layout in child pages (as we do in MVC applications).**

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but if you serve a bunch of static HTML pages via the server directly (i.e. NOT via the client), you'll have to reboot a new Angular app on each page from scratch.

Comment: @AngularFrance
reboot means, we have to reload all the configuration right ?

is that advisable ?

Comment: No, angular 2 is mostly design for SPA, and have all elements to it. If you want to build non-SPA application with angular2, you've got a problem with you'r stack definition. Maybe you need to use other javascript framework like vue.js or react who are more hybrid.

Comment: The problem is in task definition. 'don't want to go for SPA'  argument doesn't look convincing - and there are not so many good reasons that could make it valid. A2 performance will be disgusting in non-SPA scenario, and app design won't be too good, too.

Comment: Using Angular not as SPA is just wrong. As mentioned you have to reboot the hole application on each location change. But if you want to have static html delivered on first load you can look into `server side rendering` with Angular

Comment: You can always use dirty way like: `(click)="window.location.href='your route'"`, but as cyrix said- it's just wrong... 
 `server side rendering` for angular2: https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: Thanks @all for your comments. I'll use some other library then angular.